# How to show image in stimulsoft

Tags: stimulsoft

I store image path in database and use `BeforePrintEvent` event to show image in stimulsoft report and specify following code in the event:

```
Image2.Image = Image.FromFile(my Procedure Name.path column name);
```

My problem:

There are many text box and an image in my report.
my store procedure return many row and every row information show correctly in every report but first row path column in query show in image for every report.(image control in all reports show one image while it show differnt image)
my query return different path for every row.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Which Stimulsoft product do you use?
It's necessary to see your report to help you.

You don't need to use BeforePrint event. You could just set the Data Column property of the Image.

Comment: I use stimulsoft reports.net version 2012

Comment: Try the latest build